# Create a document set with JSOM

Tags: javascript, document-set, client-object-model

I'm trying to generate document sets on the fly with the following code. It is using `/_layouts/15/SP.DocumentManagement.js` for the `SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create` method which takes four parameters.

The last parameter is supposed to be a content type id object but I'm getting an exception in the console that I haven't been able to unravel. `Uncaught Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with method GetById`.

I'm following [these guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mittals/archive/2013/04/03/how-to-create-a-document-set-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-client-side-object-model-jsom.aspx) for creating it. Can anyone point me in the right direction for this error?

```
function CreateDocumentSet() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var parentFolder;
    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520008C04C8264B92224699E49B9BE493F460";

    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Source Files');
    ctx.load(list);

    parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    ctx.load(parentFolder);

    var docsetContentType = web.get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    ctx.load(docsetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder, thisItemID, docsetContentType.get_id());
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            SuccessHandler('Document Set creation successful'),
            FailureHandler("Document Set creation failed")
        );
    }, FailureHandler("Folder loading failed"));
}
```

Comment: Just one question. I have tried your code and it seems to work fine except one issue. When the Document-Set is created and modern experience is turned on the document set is shown as a folder. When you click on that folder you will not get redirected to DocSetHome.aspx... When you switch back to classic it is shown as a document-set and everythings seems to work as expected. Any ideas? Maybe there is a new method we should use in Sharepoint-Online? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most probably the specified error occurs since you are trying to get **site-level** Content Type while web is not a **root web**.

**Quick fix**

Replace the line:

```
var docsetContentType = web.get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
```

with:

```
var docsetContentType = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
```

### How to create a Document Set using JSOM

The following function demonstrates how to create a Document Set:

```
function createDocumentSet(siteUrl,listTitle,docSetName,success,error) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    ctx.load(list);

    var parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    ctx.load(parentFolder);

    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";
    var docSetContentType = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    ctx.load(docSetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (){ 
        SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.get_id());
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
    }, 
    error);
}
```

**Usage**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.documentmanagement.js', 'SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet', function() {

   createDocumentSet(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents','Orders',printInfo,logError);

   function printInfo()
   {
      console.log('Doc Set has been created');  
   }

   function logError(sender,args)
   { 
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }

});
```

Comment: That was exactly it - I was doing this a couple sites deep - thanks again Vadim.