# Create Button on Site Page to Automatically create a NEW document set (SP2013)?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Instead of clicking on the `Library` > `New Document` > `Document Set Name`, is there a way that I can bypass all of that from a command button on a Site Page? I have tried creating Shortcut to the `Create new document` dropdown link, but when doing that, it recreates the GUID (disallowing it to be unique), which creates an error.

I put this into script editor and it didn't work, but can;t figure out why:
referenced: sp.runtime.js, jquery-1.7.1.min.js, sp.js, and SP.DocumentManagement.js

Then, the entire script I used -- I excluded app.js. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div>
    <p id="text" style="font-size: medium">
    Enter a Name for the Analysis Document Set</p></div>
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="txtGetDocumentSetName" name="DocumentSetName" />
    <input type="button" id="btnCreateDocumentSet" name="bCreateDocumentSet"                                 value="Create Document Set" onclick="javascript: CreateDocumentSet()" /> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function CreateDocumentSet() {

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(SPHostUrl); 
    var parentFolder; 
    var newDocSetName = $('#txtGetDocumentSetName').val(); 
    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";

    var web = ctx.get_web(); 
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Research Document Set'); 
    ctx.load(list);

    parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder(); 
    ctx.load(parentFolder);

    var docsetContentType =         web.get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID); 
    ctx.load(docsetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () { 
    var isCreated = SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder,          newDocSetName, docsetContentType.get_id()); 
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(SuccessHandler('Document Set creation         successful'), FailureHandler("Document Set creation failed")); 
    }, FailureHandler("Folder loading failed"));


    ctx.add_requestSucceeded(function () { 
    $('#txtGetDocumentSetName').val(''); 
    alert('Request Succeeded'); 
    });

    ctx.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) { 
    alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message()); 
    }); 
    }

    // Failure Message Handler

    function FailureHandler(message) { 
       return function (sender, args) { 
            alert(message + ": " + args.get_message()); 
        } 
    }



    // Success Message Handler

    function SuccessHandler(message) { 
        return function () { 
            alert(message); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would insert a script webpart to the page and add a script like the following:

```
function createDocumentSet(siteUrl,listTitle,docSetName,success,error) {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    ctx.load(list);

    var parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    ctx.load(parentFolder);

    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";
    var docSetContentType = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    ctx.load(docSetContentType);

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (){ 
        SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(ctx, parentFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.get_id());
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(success,error);
    }, 
    error);
}
```

and then use is like this (i would add an HTML Button as you wanted and put this function onClick):

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.documentmanagement.js', 'SP.DocumentSet.DocumentSet', function() {

   createDocumentSet(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents','Orders',printInfo,logError);

   function printInfo()
   {
      console.log('Doc Set has been created');  
   }

   function logError(sender,args)
   { 
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }

});
```

Reference to SE question [Create a document set with JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114711/create-a-document-set-with-jsom)

Comment: Figured most of that out...still stuck on what 'Document' and 'Orders' is referring to. Please help if you get a sec?