# TypeError when trying to create a Document Set with JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom, document-set, jsom

I am attempting to create a document set in sharepoint online using JSOM triggered by a button. I've found the guides [referenced here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114711/create-a-document-set-with-jsom) on the subject, but I can't seem to find the issue in my code.

When trying to execute the query its throwing the error:
msajaxbundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

It seems like the Async query is failing, but im not sure why. I have also tried using list level content types and site level types with the appropriate methods for that level.

```
Lifeline.Functions.createCase = function(){
    context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var listId = '7BC07117AE-8792-43DE-984A-D6EA2A533B6C';
    list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    var docSetName = "Projection Case: Please Work ";
    list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);

    context.load(list);
    console.log("list loaded");

    var parentFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    context.load(parentFolder);
    console.log("parent folder loaded")

    var docSetContentTypeID = "0x0120D520";
    var docSetContentType =  context.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_contentTypes().getById(docSetContentTypeID);
    context.load(docSetContentType);
    console.log("doc set content type loaded");
    context.executeQueryAsync( function(){
        console.log("doc set content query executed");

        Sp.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create(context, parentFolder, docSetName, docSetContentType.get_id());
        context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler(), function logerror(sender,args){
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    },
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
};
function successHandler(){
alert("Document Set successfully Created");
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to fix the code to resolve the error. However I was able to get this working using an alternate method that seems much simpler. Hopefully it will help those who are also having difficulty executing this using `DocumentSet.DocumentSet.create` method

```
Lifeline.Functions.createCase = function(itemid) {
var docSetName = "my document set name";
var context = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById('LIST GUID');
var item;
context.load(list);

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
itemCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);
itemCreateInfo.set_leafName(docSetName);

item = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
item.set_item("ContentTypeId", "0x0120D52000307A54BE1A445A44813BEDE85E22CADB");
item.set_item('Title', docSetName);
item.set_item('DocumentSetDescription', "This is test 3 an automatically generated description");
item.set_item('ChartIdlookup', itemid);

item.update();
context.load(item);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function() { console.log("document-set created!");} ,
    function(sender,args) { console.log("Error: " + args.get_message()); }
);
```

}